# auto boot a java app fullscreen on lxle

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just downloaded a base version of LXLE.  How can I configure the system whereby on startup, it'll launch a java app full screen (covering everything possible).  The only way to navigate out of it is by closing the java app to get back to the desktop.

Additional question is how can I restart this graphic interface (restarting the java app as well) without actually rebooting the entire system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add programs to init.d directory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Here's how to write your own bash script: How can I make a script in /etc/init.d start at boot?

And sudo service lightmd restart is supposed to restart gui into login but hangs on my machine

You can also make a *.sh file and store it into /etc/profile.d for start up scripts and have it start a specific application like:

## bin/bash

cd ..
cd ..
gnome-calculator

But this is problematic! I advise against it.

Comment: Be careful, most distributions have migrated to systemd, where that works differently.